# How to check if $Ax<0$ has an answer?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry, decision-problems

Given matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$, where $m \ll n$, can I check whether $Ax<0$ has a solution $x \in \Bbb R^{n \times 1}$?

The operation $<$ is taken coordinate-wise. I am not sure but I believe my question is equal to checking whether a given $H$-polytope

$$P = \left\{ x ∈ \Bbb R^n \mid a_i^T x \leq 0,  1 \leq i \leq m \right\}$$

is empty or not.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2450754/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1360543/339790)

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to try to solve the linear optimization problem
\begin{align}
\max_{\epsilon,x}~~& \epsilon \\
\text{s.t.}& ~~Ax-\epsilon \leq 0 \\ 
& \epsilon \geq 0
\end{align}
Note that if a point $x$ exists such that $Ax < 0$ is true, then the above optimization problem has to find that. The trouble is it can be unbounded. But, this should be a starting point.